# Слайдер fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Изображение слайдера всегда больше самого экрана. и элементы управления не изменяют размер при умельшении или увеличении экрана. изображение при сжатии адаптируется хорошо, но при расширении страницы оно его не заполняет.

Как можно решить эти проблемы? Размер изображений 3200х2000

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider_img");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className = "dot";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header,
body {
  b
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider_img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav_slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 48%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: rgba(119, 204, 221, 0.8);
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-direction: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes identifier {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/slyle.css">
  <title>Aleo</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <section id="slider">
      <div class="slider_img fade">
        <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/big3/25/Winter_Sky_Snow_Fir_470882.jpg" alt="book">
      </div>
      <div class="slider_img fade">
        <img src="https://img2.akspic.ru/image/39636-zvezda-kosmicheskoe_prostranstvo-noch-nebo-nochnoe_nebo-3200x2000.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slider_img fade">
        <img src="https://www.1zoom.ru/big2/452/294626-Sepik.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095</a>
      <div class="nav_slider" style="text-align: center;">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      </div>
    </section>
    <nav>

    </nav>
  </header>

  <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что в вашем вопросе является условием, и что проблемами. Также можно давать ссылку на jsfiddle , чтобы можно было править ваш код и находить решения, а не только смотреть тут на экран.

Comment: Условием является то что слайдер должен занимать все данное ему пространство не трогая другие возможные элементы страницы, а проблема в том что слайдер вылезает за границы экрана или не заполняет экран.Не умею работать с jsfiddle.Надеюсь все правильно сделано .  https://jsfiddle.net/Rajdi/gwkdcLqn/11/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=gwkdcLqn

Comment: Думаю проще будет сначала сделать без скрипта, чтобы картинка, точки и стрелки занимали нужный размер и позиции. Это делается на CSS только, без скрипта. А скрипт в слайдерах нужен только для тех мест, которые не возможно добиться стилями, например для перемотки к нужному кадру. И с ваших слов не понятно, что значит " должен занимать все данное ему пространство не трогая другие возможные элементы страницы", потому что других элементов в примере нет, и сложно представить как это должно работать.

Comment: И ещё, элементы управления не должны обычно менять размер, потому что какой бы ни был экран, обычно удобный размер контролов одинаковый. Если это не телек.

Comment: Спасибо,я смогла добиться желаемого результата через СSS.Заключив все элементы Header в еще один блок